# Javascript code to redirect mobile phone users

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a javascript code to redirect mobile phone users. Could you check the code, I've picked it up from the net, total newb and I'd value your input regarding the quality of the script...

Does it cover all types of mobile phones?

```
function RedirectSmartphone(url) {
    if (url && url.length > 0 && IsSmartphone())
        window.location = url;
}

function IsSmartphone() {
    if (DetectUagent("android")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("iphone")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("ipod")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("symbian")) return true;
    return false;
}

function DetectUagent(name) {
    var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (uagent.search(name) > -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
RedirectSmartphone("http://mobile.version.com");
```

Comment: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ will generate code for you if you want.  I've used their code before and it works pretty well.

Comment: I don't know.  Personally I would check for screen resolution instead of sniffing the user agent.  That way you have the correct page/style for different screens.

Comment: Does it cover all types of mobile phones? **No.** What about Blackberry, WebOS, and Windows Phone 7 (to name a few)?

Comment: This looks horribly like one of those nasty "Follow a link to an article, get redirected to the mobile **homepage** scripts".

Comment: If you're only going to check the user agent, why are you doing it in client side JavaScript?

Comment: @Quentin - I hate those sites - I promptly leave and never return. My phone has a capable browser and I know how to zoom. Don't dumb it down.

Comment: I want to check for mobile phones and redirect them to my mobile version of the site...

Comment: As a user I strongly prefer a mobile redirect. Faster load-times and (hopefully) a mobile-friendly UI/nav if I want to explore. I have a great phone with a great browser, but prefer something designed <em>for that device</em> to trying to zoom/scroll and wait around on a site designed for a desktop browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending what you mean by "all the phones", but it doesn't cover, for example, blackberry phones, or tablets.

A better approach would be to detect the screen resolution, e.g. in jQuery you could do:

```
if ( (screen.width < 1024) && (screen.height < 768) ) { 
window.location = 'http://mobile.site.com';
}
```

Comment: Id like it to cover tablets, blackberry

Comment: Tablets?! Mobile versions of a site invariably suck on a 10" screen.

Comment: Ty very much for the code, makes much more sense with resolution. Can you please edit the code with a redirect to lets say http://mobile.mysite.com ?

Comment: it looked like you have already done that... :) In your mobile site, you should still check for different mobile screen sizes to support, and apply relevant sets of styles.

Answer (score 5):

I ran the code below (with the obvious slight modifications) on my site, it seems to work pretty good with Androids, iPads, iPhones and Blackberries. I am using a PHP verison for my PHP pages and this code for my CGI/PERL pages, both with the same effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RedirectSmartphone(url){
    if (url && url.length > 0 && IsSmartphone())
    window.location = url;
}
function IsSmartphone(){
    if (DetectUagent("android")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("blackberry")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("iphone")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("opera")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("palm")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("windows")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("generic")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("ipad")) return true;
    else if (DetectUagent("ipod")) return true;
    return false;
}
function DetectUagent(name){
    var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (uagent.search(name) > -1)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
RedirectSmartphone("http://mobile.version.com");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of rich resolution based mobile devices, it's probably not a good idea to leverage screen width.  You could leverage a system written in server side technology such as PHP or CGI.  There's a good tutorial over at http://www.mlynn.org/2010/06/mobile-device-detection-and-redirection-with-php/ that includes downloadable examples and scripts to help with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it covers all the phones. But would like to provide few simple ways to clean the code.

```
function IsSmartphone(){
    return (DetectUagent("android") || DetectUagent("ipod") || DetectUagent("ipod") || DetectUagent("symbian"));
}

function DetectUagent(name){
    return (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search(name) > -1);
}
```

Comment: looks way cleaner... should I use it, is it reliable? I want to be sure cause some of my earning will depend on it

Comment: Test all the devices which you are looking for. That will give you 100% confidence :)